# Project Euler Largest Prime Factor js

Tags: javascript

I have seen other answers, but am wondering why my code is not working or is maybe just taking too long to compute. It is written below.

```
function isPrime(number){
  for (var i = 2; i < number; i++){
    if (number % i === 0){
      return false
    }
  }
  return true
}

function firstNPrimes(num){
  var largestPrimeFactor = ''
  for (var i = 2; i < num/2; i++){
    if (num % isPrime(i) === 0) {
      largestPrimeFactor = i;
    }
  }
  return largestPrimeFactor;
}

console.log(firstNPrimes(600851475143));
```

Comment: I don't understand the intent behind the code. You're returning a string from a function called firstNPrimes, comparing number modulo boolean to zero, etc. Could you please describe in plain English what the goal is?

Comment: I was hoping the string would be a number. The intent was to module the num, with isPrime(i). If num % isPrime(i) === 0, it is supposed to return the largest isPrime(i).

Comment: In is prime you could check i^2 <= number and save some time. But in firstnprimes you really want to say if ((num % i == 0)&& (isPrime(i))

Comment: Please define "not working".

Comment: I am trying to solve for 600851475143 using atom and the command prompt, but it is taking forever without giving a result. I think it is because it is such a large number.

Comment: Also, if you want the largest, start at n over 2 and count down, stopping at the first you find.

Comment: thats a good idea, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So I am not looking for lots of optimizations, just finding the largest prime factor of the input, using the spirit of your routine, but fixing the mod by the boolean with seeing if i is both a divisor and prime and not checking so high to see if a number is prime and counting down, not up).
Still, I can get it correct, but with your approach it takes a very long time to check if a very large number is prime.

```js
function isPrime(n) {
    for (var i = 2; i * i <= n; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function firstNPrimes(num) {//consider better name
    if (isPrime(num)) {
        return num;
    }
    for (var i = Math.ceil(num / 2); i > 1; i--) {
        if (((num % i) == 0) && (isPrime(i))) {
        return i;
    }
}
//should never get here
return number.NaN;
}
console.log(firstNPrimes(17000));
console.log(firstNPrimes(1570000));
//do not put in very large numbers, takes too long
```

Comment: my should never get here actually does, appropriately, get there if n=1

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That all makes sense.